Adding a location based search with Drupal search api solr and search api location programmatically
What is the right way to use multiple filters in a search controller. Adding search conditions like these $query->addCondition($some_condition);  works well, but with some geospatial searches seems to be ignored when they are added like this:
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheBackendInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class SolrSearchController extends ControllerBase
{
 
public function searchContent(Request $request)
{
    $keywords = $request->query->get('search');
    $location = $request->query->get('location');
    $lat = $request->query->get('lat');
    $lng = $request->query->get('lng');
    $area = $request->query->get('area');
    $addressType = $request->query->get('addressType'); // 'city', 'country', 'continent'

    $index = Index::load('content');
    $query = $index->query();

    // Applying spatial filter if latitude and longitude are provided.
    if ($lat && $lng && $area) {
        $this->addSpatialFilter($query, $lat, $lng, $area);
    }

    // Apply search conditions, including content type filtering
    $this->applySearchConditions($query, $request, $keywords, $location);

    // Log the full query object
    \Drupal::logger('mymodule')->notice('Constructed Solr query: @query', ['@query' => json_encode($query->getOptions(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)]);

    // Execute the query
    try {
        $result = $query->execute();
        \Drupal::logger('mymodule')->notice('Solr response: @response', ['@response' => json_encode($result->getResultItems(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        \Drupal::logger('mymodule')->error('Solr query error: @message', ['@message' => $e->getMessage()]);

        return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Search query error. Please try again later.'], 500);
    }

    public function addSpatialFilter(&$query, $latitude, $longitude, $distance, $fields)
    {
        $point = "{$latitude},{$longitude}";

        $filterQueries = "{!geofilt pt=$point sfield=$field_id d=$distance}";

        $query->setOption('fq', $filterQueries);
    }
    ...

The logged Solr query ("Constructed Solr query") creates a correct query object when I test it directly in the Solr server, but it seems to be ignored this way in the $result.
Is there a best practice for using the location-based search in this cofiguration?
